# How do I set the transparency color of an image in XnView?

Tags: xnview

The image is PNG. I tried Edit > Background Color > White (FFFFFF), but it didn't set transparency. I tried Image > 32 Bits, but it didn't set transparency. Image > Edit Pallet is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

This worked: Image > Convert to Colors > 256. Image > Edit Pallet > Enable Transparency. File > Save.

Comment: I have version 1.6.4, and can't find "Edit Pallet"...